# How to add keys to values and convert to json in PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, jsonconvert

I have a string like this:

```
$string = "PackageName1,1,C:\Path
PackageName2,12,C:\Path2
PackageName3,3,C:\Path3"
```

(is a file with multilines, when I get the content I have the string above)

I want to convert this string to Json:

```
[
   {
       Pacakge: "PackageName1",
       Branch: = "1",
       LocalPath = "C:\Path"
   }

   {
       Pacakge: "PackageName2",
       Branch: = "2",
       LocalPath = "C:\Path2"
   }
]
```

I can get the values with this code:

```
$spiltted = $string.Split(' ')

ForEach ($s in $splitted)
{
   $values = $s.Split(',')
}
```

How can I add the Json keys to each value and convert it to Json object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your String looks like a csv without headers:

```
 $string | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Package,Branch,LocalPath|ConvertTo-Json
```

Sample output

```
[
    {
        "Package":  "PackageName1",
        "Branch":  "1",
        "LocalPath":  "C:\\Path"
    },
    {
        "Package":  "PackageName2",
        "Branch":  "12",
        "LocalPath":  "C:\\Path2"
    },
    {
        "Package":  "PackageName3",
        "Branch":  "3",
        "LocalPath":  "C:\\Path3"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is not a csv file but your solution works like a charm! thanks!